# Is "anti-climb paint" polluting?

Tags: environmental-impact, pollution

Is [anti-climb paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-climb_paint) polluting?

From what I've been able to find it's:

1. non-toxic
2. not for underwater use as it's bad for aquatic life
3. long lasting

In detail:

1. It's "non-toxic", such materials are chemically safe, for example eating lots of chalk powder might dangerously dry you out, but will not chemically harm you.
2. It reminds me of tar and crude oil, these are also bad for aquatic life. I would expect some anti-climb paint to make its way into the water supply. I would also expect the substance to be broken down by the environment and effectively have a half-life of potential harm.
3. Could exacerbate other problems.